# Automating combo boxes having same DIV class

Tags: java, selenium, combobox

I am trying to automate the Naukari.com CREATE JOB ALERT page in that we have INDUSTRY field and JOB ROLE field. Both are Combo box with checkboxes.For INDUSTRY field i used the below script.

```
 //Clicking on the industry dropdown
 //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@placeholder,'Type or   Select')]")).click();

 //Selecting the checkbox containing text as "Accounting"
 //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ChkboxEnb']//a[contains(text(),'Accounting')]")).click();

 //Selecting the checkbox containing text as 'Government' 
 //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='ChkboxEnb']//a[contains(text(),'Government')]")).click();
```

But for JOB ROLE field I'm again facing the issue since the div class is same. I also tried using `//input[contains(@id,'given_id')]")).click();`

But its not working. Please help!!

Comment: Go for child attributes. select the DOM on basis of class name then go by using children attribute. It will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code **(working for both FF and Chrome)**:

```
    //Sending blank to the industry dropdown so the list is visible
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='cjaInd']")).sendKeys("");

    Actions act = new Actions(driver);

    //Selecting the checkbox containing text exactly as "Accounting , Finance"
    act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='indCja']//ul[@class='ChkboxEnb']//a[.='Accounting , Finance']"))).click().perform();

    //Selecting the checkbox containing text exactly as 'Strategy , Management Consulting Firms' 
    act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='indCja']//ul[@class='ChkboxEnb']//a[.='Strategy , Management Consulting Firms']"))).click().perform();

    //For clicking outside so as the dropdown closes and we can proceed with other action(s)
    act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[.='Industry']"))).click().perform();

    //Sending blank to the Job Category dropdown so the list is visible
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='cjaJob']")).sendKeys("");

    //Selecting the checkbox containing text exactly as Application Programming, Maintenance
    act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='jcCja']//ul[@class='ChkboxEnb']//a[.='Application Programming, Maintenance']"))).click().perform();

    //Selecting the checkbox containing text exactly as "Site Engineering, Project Management"
    act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='jcCja']//ul[@class='ChkboxEnb']//a[.='Site Engineering, Project Management']"))).click().perform();

    //For clicking outside so as the dropdown closes and we can proceed with other action(s)
    act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[.='Industry']"))).click().perform();
```

Comment: Hi Shubh, I want to automate both the combo box simultaneously i.e. INDUSTRY and JOB CATEGORY. Using only one at a time is working.

Comment: @Shubh: Nope, it is populating the INDUSTRY but not JOB CATEGORY :(

Comment: What error is it throwing, can you tell me please @Riki ?

Comment: @Shubh:It is throwing this error------unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (627, 423). Other element would receive the click: <a href="javascript:;" data-id="indCja_a23">...</a>

Comment: @Riki: I am running it at my end, and it is working fine. Are you using the exact same code above or have you modified something as per your need ?

Comment: @Shubh: I'm using the same code. Are using using Chrome browser, I'm facing issue in Chrome.

Comment: Oh! It's working properly in firefox though. Have you tried there? Or do you want it to run in Chrome only ?

Comment: Firefox is not working at my end there is some issue. Can you try once on Chrome and let me know if its working?

Comment: @Riki: Have modified the code. It is working in both FF and Chrome. Please let me know if it works for you too.

Comment: @Shubh: Now its not showing the error but the form window is getting closed as soon as its appearing. Can you handle that too :)

Comment: which form window are you talking about ?

Comment: Create a job alert window or popup in whcih we are filling INDUSTRY and JOB CATEGORY.

Comment: That is not happening for me. Anyways, is it filling INDUSTRY and JOB CATEGORY fields properly, with the checked checkboxes values?

Comment: Can you give the whole code you are using i think i have added few windowhandlers in my code. And i can't see if its filling or not because as soon as its flashing its getting closed.

Comment: Ok done i adjusted some code..now its working!! :)Thanks a lot . You rock man.